# pg_connect is pretty slow in case of error

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php script that is used to store some info in a postgresql db. In this script I am using a function to store some logs about certain db operations. During tests I found out that my script will log my errors related to pg_connect function, only after 4-5 seconds - and this represents a big issue for me.

Below you can find my tests and the results:

***Case 1*** - no error in pg_connect function:

```
    Log("START DBCONN - without errors");

    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpassword");

        if(!$dbconn){
           Log("ERROR: Could not connect to database");
        }

    Log("END");
```

***Case 2*** - error in pg_connect:

```
    Log("START DBCONN - with errors");

    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=$host12 dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpassword");

        if(!$dbconn){
           Log("ERROR: Could not connect to database");
        }

    Log("END");
```

***Results***

*case 1:*

```
[12-Jan-2016 09:31:21] START DBCONN - without errors

[12-Jan-2016 09:31:21] END
```

*case 2:*

```
[12-Jan-2016 09:31:59] START DBCONN - with errors

[12-Jan-2016 09:32:03] ERROR: Could not connect to database

[12-Jan-2016 09:32:03] END
```

Do you know a solution for this ? because, I couldn't find one, yet :(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does the issue also occur in your local development environment?

Comment: I'd suggest you to attempt using PDO instead of the native postgres driver and see if it keeps giving you the same issue, otherwise it could be an internal connectivity issue.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the nature of the errors, there may be different reasons for it:

- If the username or password is wrong, the server may delay the negative response to make brute-forcing a valid combination more cumbersome.
- If the host is not reachable, the tcp connect timeout may be several seconds.

Both issues are hard to fix in a clean way.

There are also error conditions which should not result in a delay, for example:

- if the host is reachable, but the database server is not running (i.e. "Connection refused").

Answer (score 1):

The time to fail in case of a non-responding remote host can be adjusted with the `connect_timeout` option in the `pg_connect()` call.

PHP's `pg_connect()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) does not give any detail on `connect_timeout` but it just passes it to libpq, the C client library, where it's documented as:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html

> **connect_timeout**
>
> Maximum wait for connection, in seconds (write as a decimal integer string). Zero or not specified means wait indefinitely. It is
>   not recommended to use a timeout of less than 2 seconds.

However, the 4 seconds before failure shown in the question seem reasonable for a TCP problem. If you expect recurring network errors with your database host, maybe a local connection pooler like [pgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) should be considered, to insulate the web environnement from these high-latency errors.

Comment: Also note that if you use something like pgBouncer, you need one `connect_timeout` between the PHP process and pgBouncer, and another between the pgBouncer and the backend database.